# Is there any way I can change the targeting reticule?

Tags: antichamber

The targeting reticule in *Antichamber* is very minimalist (likely the intention), merely a small white dot with a thin black circle. While I'd normally appreciate the unintrusive UI, I sometimes suffer from motion sickness when playing games from a first person POV, and the combination of the low FOV and the fact that the targeting reticule so easily blends in with the background makes it so I can play this game only in very short sittings before I start to feel ill.

While the low FOV contributes to this, I'm loath to change the FOV because of the number of puzzles I've come across so far that change depending on the direction you're looking or actually *require* you to be looking in a different direction. Seeing as I'd like to try to play the game "as intended" as possible, I'd prefer only to do this as a last resort. I figure if I can at least give my eyes something more obvious to focus on, it will help prevent me from becoming so quickly nauseated.

Is there any way I can easily replace the file for the targeting reticule with something custom made that's a bit larger/obvious? I know the game's made in the Unreal Engine, so I figure there should be a way to do this. I have no experience modding the Unreal Engine 3 at all though, so thorough steps would be appreciated. I'm running this on a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but it's very tedious. Since Antichamber runs on the Unreal Engine, the files are packed in Unreal Engine-specific archives.

[This forum post](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/587632-Howto-Extracting-Textures-amp-Custom-Crosshairs?p=25120214#post25120214) has the matter neatly explained for Unreal Tournament 3. The same procedure can, in theory, be performed on Antichamber, given it's also running on UE3.